# Integrate wallet connect on my website

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, walletconnect

How do I integrate walletconnect on my website. Just link it is on pinksale.finance.

Haven't found anything straight forward online.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple frameworks for this.

- [Onboard.js](https://docs.blocknative.com/onboard)
- [Web3Modal](https://github.com/Web3Modal/web3modal#readme)
- [Snapshot Lock](https://github.com/snapshot-labs/lock#readme)

All of these frameworks provide extensive documentation on how to integrate these.

Comment: I see how the code works, but I am lost with how to integrate like this: https://example.walletconnect.org/ and receive payments on my website. 

The Guide doesn't say what code block works for what. In this documenation https://docs.walletconnect.com/1.0/quick-start/dapps/client, where do I send token out and how do I get the users address to send out from?